# How to "Connect" two variables between two React Components?

Tags: reactjs, tic-tac-toe

```
import Board from './components/Board';
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <Board />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import Square from './Square';
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Board() {
    const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);
    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null))
    function handleClick(i){
        if (squares[i]){
            return;
        }
        const nextSquares = squares.slice();
        if (xIsNext) {
            nextSquares[i] = "X";
        }
        else {
            nextSquares[i] = "O";
        }
        setSquares(nextSquares);
        setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
    }
    return (
  
        <>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
            <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
            <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
            <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
            <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
            <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
            <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
        </div>
        </>  
    );
}
```

```
import Board from "./Board";

export default function Header({xIsNext}){

    return (
        <>
        <h1>Now is turn of Player: {xIsNext ? "X" : "O"}</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```

Hey, i'm learning React so due to [React.dev tic-tac-toe](https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) tutorial i've made simple tic-tac-toe game. Without game logic like winner yet, but at this moment I think that i need to implement a Header component, which task is to say which turn of player is by getting "xIsNext" value and if True - showing X, if not - showing O... - but it doesn't work. Whatever is happening, my header shows only "O" player turn. Im really greatful for any solutions in future, thanks!

Comment: If state is used across components it must live “above” or outside those components. Search for “react lift star” or similar. Right not the header component expects a property which you never pass in.

Answer (score 2):

You should move the useState to parent component then pass them as props

import Board from './components/Board';
import Header from './components/Header';

```
function App() {
  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header xIsNext={xIsNext} />
      <Board xIsNext={xIsNext} setXIsNext={setXIsNext} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After that you can get them in child components like this

```
import Square from './Square';
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Board({xIsNext, setXIsNext}) {

    const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null))
    function handleClick(i){
        if (squares[i]){
            return;
        }
        const nextSquares = squares.slice();
        if (xIsNext) {
            nextSquares[i] = "X";
        }
        else {
            nextSquares[i] = "O";
        }
        setSquares(nextSquares);
        setXIsNext(!xIsNext);
    }
    return (
  
        <>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
            <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
            <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
            <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
            <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
            <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
            <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
            <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
        </div>
        </>  
    );
}
```

```
import Board from "./Board";

export default function Header({xIsNext}){

    return (
        <>
        <h1>Now is turn of Player: {xIsNext ? "X" : "O"}</h1>
        </>
    );
}
```